# PHP delete unwanted characters from a textarea list

Tags: php

I have a textarea I have submitted via a form.

Then I get the text from it:

```
$textArea = $_POST['my_textarea']; 

$textArea's content is this:

myemail1.com=somethinge
myemail2.com=somethingelse
myemail3.com=somethingel
```

My problem is that I need to take off all the characters after the = sign.

So, once done it should look like this:

```
myemail1.com
myemail2.com
myemail3.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Is every email guaranteed to be separated by a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$emails = array();

$temp = explode("\r\n", $_POST['my_textarea']);
foreach ($temp as $line)
{
    $tmp = explode("=", $line);
    $emails[] = $tmp[0];
}

print_r($emails);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the emails are each on their own respective lines, this preg_replace should strip all of the excess for you:

```
$cleanEmails = preg_replace( "/(\.[a-z]{2,4})=.*$/", "$1", $textArea );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
$emails = array_keys(parse_ini_string($textarea));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp